# URL name vs indexing

Tags: seo, directory, google-search

I found out that google will only index the top level URL from my site but i have a blog in my site as well that i want it to be listed in blog directories.

so my question is:

since i name the blog under **www.mydomain.com/blog.html** it is certain that google will only take www.mydomain.com in to consideartion.

so what if i name my blog such a way: **www.blog.mydomain.com**?
would this be consider as another entity? if so how do i name it such way?

P/s: My blog and Site both has different content of the same topic and i want them to be listed in both web and blog directories.

Comment: If you've linked the pages up then Google have most likely indexed them, but if you do a search for your website Google won't necessarily show you every page available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Canoical Meta tag:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

For example: on your blog (in both places), add the meta tag: `<link rel="canonical" href="http://blog.example.com/" />`

It applies for static, and dynamic pages.

Comment: hi CJ, the page you posted was talking about how to manipulate dynamic URL but i need a static URL for my Blog.. could you suggest another method?

Comment: so if i use the same URL (xx.com/blog.htlm) will be a valid link for directory listing, if i put that in meta tag?

Comment: It will work, if you put it on any two pages, that have the same content. It doesn't depend on directory structure or certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

Subfolders have preference over subdomains.

So **http://www.domain.com/blog** is better for your SEO than **http://blog.domain.com**

The reason for this is that a subdomain is a completely different website in the eyes of Google, but a subfolder is an extension of the main website.

Therefor the subfolder will benefit from links pointing to the main website and the main website will also benefit from links pointing to the subfolder.